# Why is Clion giving me an error when I declare a struct inside a function?

Tags: c++, clion

[image]
The application compiles without any issues, however Clion says that my code has an error. What could be the reason? If I move the declaration outside the function, it doesn't give me any errors.

Comment: This does not look like C.

Comment: thanks, I removed the tag.

Comment: What does compiler say?

Comment: nothing, it compiles as expected without any problems.

Comment: @jsguy [facepalm]

Comment: @bolov, could you elaborate?

Comment: don't trust your IDE. The compiler is the one that compiles your code.

Comment: @jsguy -\_- If the compiler finds no errors, then there _are no_ errors. Just because CLion _thinks_ something is wrong doesn't mean something _is actually wrong_. Only believe what your compiler says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's because I come from a time where intellisense was so unreliable, frequently failing to update and act on the new code I just wrote, or frequently crashing completely, or messing its cache or sowing errors on the word I was just typing, or not being updated with the new implemented feature in the compiler or etc. etc., but I am being constantly baffled by people freezing and panicking when the intellisense shows a false positive or just goes nuts when in fact there is nothing wrong.

Don't rely so much on your IDE realtime error checking! The compiler is the one that compiles your code. **The compiler is the only one that matters!**

The rest are just **tools to help you code**. If they fail you are still expected to be able to write code.